# In the Red programming language, how does one compile a script?

Tags: compilation, red

I've compiled scripts in Red before, but once I've been away from it for a while, I forget.  I thought I'd ask the question here because I'm sure I'm not the only one.

How does one compile a script in the Red programming language?

I've searched my Red distribution folder in the "Docs" directory, and also looked on http://red-lang.org, but didn't see the instructions.  I know I've seen it somewhere before, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Looks like the instructions are in the README: https://github.com/dockimbel/Red

Comment: As @Blender says... perhaps you should be more specific, because it compiles to a binary if you follow the directions.  :-/  Can you get the "Hello Red" program?  That would be a good start.  You will need to do a Git Clone of the Red repository and you will need to get a Rebol2 interpreter, but that should be the only requirements on all platforms.  *(I've ported it to Rebol3 but changes have not gotten upstream yet, due to politics and such.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically, thanks to @Blender, the information is available at https://github.com/dockimbel/Red.

I knew I saw the information before, but I couldn't remember where.  I checked the "Docs" folder in the Red distribution, but that didn't have the information there (might be handy to add it).

1. Start the Rebol interpreter in the folder where the Red files and folders are stored.
2. For Red: `>> do/args %red.r "%red/tests/console.red"`
3. For Red/System: `do/args %rsc.r "%tests/hello.reds"`

See the link for more detailed instructions.

Comment: FWIW: There is a readme.md file in the Red distribution.  If you're on Windows, the line breaks will not be friendly, even if you figure out you can open it with Notepad or similar.  To view the readme.md file in a readable format on Windows, run rebol.exe and type `>> editor %readme.md`.

Comment: FYI: the ".md" extension means ["MarkDown"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (e.g. this format we use to make `[hyperlinks](with brackets)`).  We feel your pain...technology is a moving target...so if you look for README.TXT you won't find it these days!

Comment: I'm back in this world, sort of revenant mode.

Actually, I wanted to put a shebang at the top of my Red script, it didn't work out; and I stumbled upon this hilarious exchange.
Thanks for the laugh.

I'm going to read a few READHIM.md:
locate README.md | xargs less